# Is there lunchtime analogue of the 'breakfast of champions' idiom?

Tags: idioms

In British English (possibly US too) there is an an idiom which it is to suggest that something is the 'breakfast of champions' when the content of the breakfast is particularly notable.

- Perhaps a large quantity of breakfast.
- Perhaps something that would not normally be eaten for breakfast.
- Perhaps its not technically a breakfast but in the context of breakfast.

Is there a lunchtime analogue of this idiom? Or a phrase that can be used in a similar context where the meal concerned is lunch.

Note I am not looking for 'lunch of champions' but real unadulterated idioms.

Comment: The "Breakfast of Champions" is not an idiom. It's [advertising](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheaties).

Comment: It may have been used in advertising in the past, but that doesn't mean it hasn't become an idiom since. Certainly in the UK, where the aforementioned advertisements were never shown (nor the cereal in question ever marketed at all apparently), its usage is far more likely to be idiomatic, or as a reference to the Kurt Vonnegut novel, than it is to be a reference to a foreign advertising campaign that ran over 50 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the term [Power Lunch](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20of%20power%20lunch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=power%20lunch%20recipes&revid=1095577147&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official) is both common and its slang definition fits your needs.  In the corporate world it would simply mean a meeting of top officials over lunch but in common usage it would imply a high-energy meal at lunch.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

"Breakfast of Champions" was an advertising slogan used by Wheaties brand cereal at least as far back as the 1950s. To the best of my knowledge that's where the phrase originated. They would regularly run ads with some champion athlete saying how he eats their cereal, rather implying that he became the heavyweight champion of the world or whatever just because he eats Wheaties, and then end with the slogan, "Wheaties -- the breakfast of champions!" The point, by the way, wasn't that it was a large breakfast or an unusual breakfast, but that Wheaties was supposedly very nutritious and would give you energy or something to perform your best for the day.

If this has become an idiom for something in Britain, I wouldn't know. Here in the U.S., people will occasionally use it as a joke, like have some totally non-nutritious breakfast -- a pop-tart or a beer or something -- and say, "Yes, the breakfast of champions." I've never heard it used in any other context.

Comment: It is also a 1973 novel by the American author Kurt Vonnegut.

Comment: Yes. I've never read the novel, but I see there's a Wikipedia page on it that includes the statement, "The title, taken from the well-known slogan for Wheaties breakfast cereal, crops up in a key scene late in the novel when a waitress, apparently ironically, says "Breakfast of Champions" each time she serves a customer a martini." Which, amusingly enough, rather parallels my answer above.

Comment: It was a phrase used for meaning a hearty breakfast of things like eggs, biscuits, sausage, gravy.  Wheaties figured they had sports figures hence they could borrow it and also imply that their cereal would replace that hearty meal at no cost to said champion.  Great advertising.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd "It was a phrase used for meaning a hearty breakfast of things like eggs, biscuits, sausage, gravy. " - do you have any citations to back this up? Because [I'm not seeing it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22breakfast+of+champions%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20breakfast%20of%20champions%20%22%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @DigitalChris - Ngram is a tool not a fact.  I went to school for advertising and specifically remember Wheaties example in the late 30s early 40s.  They were having trouble having it trademarked because the phrase was in existence.  Why it wasn't in a book that google scanned.  I don't know.

Comment: I'm not saying my link is somehow a fact; I'm saying your proposed fact that "It was a phrase used for meaning a hearty breakfast of things like eggs, biscuits, sausage, gravy." is not true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always fond of a bit of alliteration, and to tie in somewhat to Breakfast of Champions, how about

> Lunch of Legends

?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is such an idiom pertaining exclusively to lunch, and I can't find anything appropriate in a [search for idioms containing 'lunch'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lunch) on The Free Dictionary.

The closest I can think of is 'a lunch fit for a King'. However, this isn't a fixed phrase, and although I personally associate the idiom 'fit for a king' with food, it [can apparently be applied](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fit+for+a+king) to any other context involving luxury and indulgence.

Answer (score -2):

I think "Liquid Lunch" fits the bill rather well, particularly in the context of KVJ's ironic use of BoC.